# Jquery append() for shuffling links in rails admin dashboard

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, arrays, append

So I have a view for my admin dashboard. I have the list of pages that an admin can create, and posts (page content) belong to pages. A real simple CMS for a website someone can build where at least they have some level of customization. I'm new to rails development and development in general but I was wondering if anyone could tell me how I could get the up and down buttons at the top you see there to shuffle the order of the pages? By clicking up it does an append to the array of the target element and down does prepend...

I know it's probably a few lines of jquery but I can't seem to get it to work. I haven't worked with Javascript or Jquery in years! And I'm just now getting back into development after a nice long hiatus.

Any ideas would be welcomed!

Here's a screenshot of the admin dashboard at the moment:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vj1L.png)

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<html>
<h1>Dashboard</h1>
<body>

<h2>Site Pages</h2>
<div class="dashboard-container">
  <div class="sidebar-left">
    Links <button type="button" id=" link-up">Up</button><button id="link-down" type="button">Down</button>
  </div>
        <% @admin_pages.each do |page| %>

        <div class="admin_page_div" id="page_div">
          <span class="page_name"><b><%= page.name %></b></span><br />
            <button type="button"><%= link_to "view", admin_page_path(page), {:style=>'color:white;'}%></button>
            <button type="button"><%= link_to "edit", edit_admin_page_path(page), {:style=>'color:white;'}%></button>
            <button type="button"><%= link_to "delete", admin_page_path(page), :style=>'color:white;', method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure? This will delete all the posts, too"} %></button>
            <br>
        </div>
        <% end %>
    <div class="sidebar-right">
      Content
    </div>
</div>
<br>

<button type="buttone"><%= link_to 'New Admin Page', new_admin_page_path, {:style=>'color:white;'} %></button><button type="buttone"><%= link_to 'New Blog Entry', new_admin_home_blog_path, {:style=>'color:white;'} %></button>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify a bit more of what you want the "up" button and "down" buttons to do specifically? I'm a bit confused of what you mean by shuffling the pages in the list.

Comment: Sure! Down would take the first object in the array and make it the second. Pushing the button again would make it third, and so on. Pushing up would go in the other direction. Maybe this isn't the best way of reordering the divs containing the links to the pages, but it's just an idea of a feature I'd like to implement where someone can at least change the order of the links if they want to.

Comment: Oh okay, thank you! So it's fine that the list order resets when the page is reloaded?

Comment: No it's not fine that it resets lol. I wasn't thinking this through. I may have to build a ruby method in the model to get the same effect I was hoping to achieve through JS or Jquery so that it changes the order of the links permanently. Like I said in the description of this question, total newb. I am not very knowledgable as a developer at all. Just learning!

Comment: In general, that's a lot of work for some functionality that won't really affect end users. But do you want me to post an answer of how I've managed the order of models in past so you can see an example of how to do that anyway?

Comment: Sure! I love looking over people's code to see how they accomplish neat things like that. And I get where you're coming from. I'm just eager to learn new things and become a more competent developer that can do more than make a to-do list or blog lol.